# Cannot go back to main ssrs report from a drill thru report in Chrome report viewer

Tags: angularjs, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, subreport

I have a SSRS report with includes a Drill Through report.  When I run the report from Report Manager and click the link to go to the Drill Through Report, there is a 'Back' button so the user can go back to the main report.

When I display this same report in my AngularJS application that has a Report Viewer, I can go to the Drill Through Report when I click the link but I cannot go back to the main report. If I use the back button on the Google Chrome Browser, I have to re-enter all of the parameters of the report.

Does the Report Viewer not allow a user to go back to a main report from a subreport?

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: My SSRS version is SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

From the SSRS 2008 R2 documentation on [Browser Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.105).aspx):

> To run Report Manager and use Report Manager to view reports, you **must** use Microsoft **Internet Explorer 6.0 or higher** and scripting must be enabled. **Internet Explorer 8.0 or higher is recommended.**

Google Chrome is not a supported browser, which is probably why you are missing some functionality.

Comment: I see.  I found work around.  Go to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384755/how-to-link-back-to-parent-report-in-ssrs