# Back to parent button not showing up

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My Back to Parent Button seems to disappear.  Anyone know how I can turn it on?  I've looked at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670.aspx) Microsoft article, but I don't know where to configure the AlwaysAsynchronous mode and set ShowBackButton to true.  I'm using Reporting Services 2016 and VS 2017 to develop my reports.  I must be missing something obvious?

Incidentally, it does show up with this URL (also see With the Back to Parent Button):

```
http://myServer/reports/report/Purchasing/Copy%20of%20List%20Purchase%20Orders
```

With the Back to Parent Button:
[image]

But not with this URL (also see Without the Back to Parent Button):

```
http://myServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Purchasing/Copy%20of%20List%20Purchase%20Orders
```

Without the Back to Parent Button:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573582/cannot-go-back-to-main-ssrs-report-from-a-drill-thru-report-in-chrome-report-vie

Comment: I looked at that link.  I was really hoping MS wouldn't still want me to use IE.  I'm trying to get my users off IE.  In IE the normal back button works just like the "Back to parent" button.  But in both Chrome and Edge, the back button doesn't work to hold parameters or scroll position.  Therefore, I need the "Back to Parent" button.  I've also tried the javascript work around.  It works just like the browser back button.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Please Microsoft, can you fix this issue with the ReportViewer in SSRS.  Or someone please give an answer that actually works preserving the parameters like the "Back to parent" button does.  All manually created back buttons and the example below do not preserve the parameters..  It is very annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back to this question and worked out my own solution.  I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017) Microsoft article to create my own WebForms Report Viewer that has the "Back to Parent" button showing.  I haven't deployed it to production yet, but it works in all my tests.  I'm planning on running it on the same server where Reporting Services is running.

Seems like it should have been easier to turn on the "Back to Parent" button in the "ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx" application, but I couldn't find it.  It actually wasn't that hard to create my own version.  So in the end, as long as it works, I'm happy.  The only lingering issue is that the auto emails that go out from Reporting Services will have the old server address in them.  I think the users can work around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "&rc%3ashowbackbutton=true" to the end of your report viewer url.